# netblock ip - own hosting - home servers

Tags: web-hosting, server, ip-address

I host 2 websites that generate a pretty substantial traffic (about 6000 unique visitors a day both). I have business Internet at home and I own one static IP from my ISP. I run my own servers. However, I want to know why some other websites when I run a search on:

```
http://whoishostingthis.com/
```

OR

```
http://infosniper.net/
```

display the provider or hosted company as themselves, even though they are not crazy big sites, but my site is displayed as being hosted by my ISP. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A whois record should display your registration info unless you chose to use private registration. And a whois search on an IP will show who the ip block is registered to, and is almost always your ISP.

If you want to have your own company info show up in an IP lookup, then you need to obtain a [provider-independent address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_Independent_Address_Space). This can be done through a [regional internet registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry) or through a [local internet registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Internet_registry).

However, it's generally not worth it to get your own independent address space. They cost over $1000 a year to lease (from RIPE, the RIR for Europe and North-West Asia, it's 2000 euros for the first year and 1300 after that). The only reason you would get one is for multihoming or to avoid losing or having to change your IP if you switch ISPs or your ISP goes under. But since most internet applications are capable of using DNS routing, this too is rarely an issue.

Spending that much money just to have your company info listed in a whois lookup of your IP address (who's gonna look that up anyway?) is just crazy.

**Edit:** It might be cheaper to get your independent address space from an LIR if you're only trying to get a small IP block, but I'm not sure how much cheaper or what the minimum block size is. Also, with RIRs, you have to demonstrate a need for your own PI address space.

Comment: Wouldn't getting the net block owner (your ISP) to add a Reverse PTR Record do what you want?

Comment: @anthonyg: I don't think a PTR record is what he's looking for. AFAIK, a PTR record just lets you resolve a hostname to an IP. That is separate from the registration info displayed in an IP lookup, which is what the 2 sites he mentioned uses to identify the ISP's organization name (`OrgTechName`).